# DataGrid Background Binding to Jagged Array

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, datagrid

I have an array `byte[][] colourMapping`, and I want to manipulate a DataGrid such that it is bound to the array (but not in the traditional sense, I believe). I don't want to display the contents of the array in the grid, but rather would like to change specific cell background's depending on the value of the array (I would like the cells themselves to be blank).

For example, if colourMapping[0][0] == 27, then I'd like the datagrid's cell at [0][0] to have a certain colour background.

Additionally, as the values of the array change, I'd like the datagrid's background to change accordingly.

I know this is a general question, but how do I go about doing this?

UPDATE:

Here's what I currently have. It fills in a datagrid with the bytes themselves (which is something I want to avoid), and doesn't seem to set the background:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //mt.BinaryMapping is a byte[][]
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = BindingHelper.GetBindable2DViewFromIList<byte>(mt.BinaryMapping);
    }

    private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn column = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        Binding binding = column.Binding as Binding;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath(binding.Path.Path + ".Value");
    }
}

public class Ref<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> getter;
    private readonly Action<T> setter;
    public Ref(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter)
    {
        this.getter = getter;
        this.setter = setter;
    }
    public T Value { get { return getter(); } set { setter(value); } }
}

public class BindingHelper
{
    public static DataView GetBindable2DViewFromIList<T>(IList list2d)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < ((IList)list2d[0]).Count; i++)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(Ref<T>));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list2d.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        for (int i = 0; i < list2d.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ((IList)list2d[i]).Count; j++)
            {
                int a = i;
                int b = j;
                Ref<T> refT = new Ref<T>(() => (list2d[a] as IList<T>)[b], z => { (list2d[a] as IList<T>)[b] = z; });
                dataView[i][j] = refT;
            }
        }
        return dataView;
    }
}

public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte s = (byte)value;
        if (s == 255)
        {
            return Brushes.DeepPink;
        }
        else if (s == 237)
        {
            return Brushes.Blue;
        }
        else
        {
            return Brushes.White;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And here's my DataGrid, which displays the bytes in the cells (undesirable behaviour, but manageable), and can't seem to properly set the background colour:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" HeadersVisibility="None" RowHeaderWidth="0" ColumnHeaderHeight="0" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Have you started somewhere or are you asking us to do the job for you?

Comment: You need a to set a DataGrid.CellStyle with a setter on background with the value of , 
Value={Binding Path=. , Converter={StaticResource SomeHexToBrushConverter

Comment: @devhedgehog I've updated my question with what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CellFormatting event to set the background color without binding the array to the grid.

For my test I used an array of Color instead of byte.

```
Color[,] colourMapping = new Color[8,9];

 public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      for (int i = 0; i < colourMapping.GetLength(0); i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < colourMapping.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
          colourMapping[i,j] = Color.Beige;
        }
      }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.RowIndex < colourMapping.GetLength(0) && e.ColumnIndex < colourMapping.GetLength(1))
      {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = colourMapping[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex];
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe that CellFormatting is in WPF.

Comment: Sorry.  Missed the "wpf" tag.  (The original question didn't have any code)